# Mass around mode in high dimensional Gaussian

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, high-dimensional

I came across this quote in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.02918). The paper is about training a classfier on images with added Gaussian noise $\delta \sim N(x, \sigma^2I)$. The paper states:

> In high dimension, the Gaussian distribution $N(x, \sigma^2I)$ places almost no mass near its mode $x$.

**Question:**

Why is this statement true? Why is there almost no mass around the mode of the distribution in high dimension?

Comment: Search our site for posts on [the curse of dimensionality](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=curse+dimension*+is%3Aanswer+score%3A5). You can also carry out an instructive calculation: when the dimension is $n,$ the mass within distance $Z\sigma$ of $x$ cannot exceed $(\Phi(Z)-\Phi(-Z))^n$ (which would be the mass within the circumscribed hypercube) and, for a fixed $Z,$ this decreases exponentially in $n.$

Answer (score -1):

In high dimensions, absolutely continuous distributions place almost no mass everywhere.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There's actually a little more to it than that... it turns out that the mass largely resides in a "shell" some distance away from the mode... see for example https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419412/why-is-gaussian-distribution-on-high-dimensional-space-like-a-soap-bubble.